# Grid Background image won't load once the program compiled

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

Ok, i'm currently developping a metro app on windows 8.1 platform and i have this little issue with the background image of my main page.

```
 <Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets\Wallpaper.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid.Background>
```

in the xaml designer, the image is correctly displayed but isn't anymore once i compile my program.
Wallpaper.jpg is built on content.

Comment: Where's this view located ? in the root project, or inside a folder ?

Comment: @AymenDaoudi The view is located in the root project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably happening because of te ImageSource source formatting, your view may be inside a folder or something similar, Try to use this :

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Wallpaper.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

This should work.